Issue with carla make PythonAPI
make PythonAPI
BuildUE4Plugins.sh: Downloading STREETMAP plugin.
Cloning into '/media/y/e/carla-ue4-dev/Unreal/CarlaUE4/Plugins/Streetmap'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 423, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (162/162), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (96/96), done.
remote: Total 423 (delta 75), reused 120 (delta 64), pack-reused 261 (from 1)
Receiving objects: 100% (423/423), 17.86 MiB | 3.37 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (191/191), done.
Note: checking out '260273d6b7c3f28988cda31fd33441de7e272958'.
You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:
git checkout -b
HEAD is now at 260273d Correct descriptor
BuildUE4Plugins.sh: StreetMap Success!
Setup.sh: Retrieving boost.
--2024-10-26 08:39:31-- https://archives.boost.io/release/1.80.0/source/boost_1_80_0.tar.gz
Resolving archives.boost.io (archives.boost.io)... 199.232.191.52
Connecting to archives.boost.io (archives.boost.io)|199.232.191.52|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 136670223 (130M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘boost_1_80_0.tar.gz’
boost_1_80_0.tar.gz 100%[===================>] 130.34M 10.6MB/s in 13s
2024-10-26 08:39:44 (9.99 MB/s) - ‘boost_1_80_0.tar.gz’ saved [136670223/136670223]
Elapsed Time downloading from boost webpage: 13 seconds
Setup.sh: Extracting boost for Python 3.
Elapsed Time Extracting boost for Python: 3 seconds
Building B2 engine..
Using 'clang' toolset.
Ubuntu clang version 11.0.1-2~18.04.sav0
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
clang++ -x c++ -std=c++11 -O3 -s -DNDEBUG builtins.cpp class.cpp command.cpp compile.cpp constants.cpp cwd.cpp debug.cpp debugger.cpp execcmd.cpp execnt.cpp execunix.cpp filesys.cpp filent.cpp fileunix.cpp frames.cpp function.cpp glob.cpp hash.cpp hcache.cpp hdrmacro.cpp headers.cpp jam_strings.cpp jam.cpp jamgram.cpp lists.cpp make.cpp make1.cpp md5.cpp mem.cpp modules.cpp native.cpp object.cpp option.cpp output.cpp parse.cpp pathnt.cpp pathsys.cpp pathunix.cpp regexp.cpp rules.cpp scan.cpp search.cpp startup.cpp subst.cpp sysinfo.cpp timestamp.cpp variable.cpp w32_getreg.cpp modules/order.cpp modules/path.cpp modules/property-set.cpp modules/regex.cpp modules/sequence.cpp modules/set.cpp -o b2
tools/build/src/engine/b2
Unicode/ICU support for Boost.Regex?... /usr
Generating B2 configuration in project-config.jam for clang...

Bootstrapping is done. To build, run:
./b2
To generate header files, run:
./b2 headers
The configuration generated uses clang to build by default. If that is
unintended either use the --with-toolset option or adjust configuration, by
editing 'project-config.jam'.
Further information:
Command line help:
./b2 --help

Getting started guide:
http://www.boost.org/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

B2 documentation:
http://www.boost.org/build/

/media/y/e/carla-ue4-dev/Build/boost-1.80.0-c10-source/tools/build/src/tools/common.jam:1140: in common.find-compiler from module common
error: toolset clang-linux initialization:
error: version '10.0' requested but 'clang++-10.0' not found and version '11.0.1' of default 'clang++' does not match
error: initialized from
/media/y/e/carla-ue4-dev/Build/boost-1.80.0-c10-source/tools/build/src/tools/clang-linux.jam:52: in clang-linux.init from module clang-linux
/media/y/e/carla-ue4-dev/Build/boost-1.80.0-c10-source/tools/build/src/build/toolset.jam:44: in toolset.using from module toolset
/media/y/e/carla-ue4-dev/Build/boost-1.80.0-c10-source/tools/build/src/tools/clang.jam:33: in clang.init from module clang
/media/y/e/carla-ue4-dev/Build/boost-1.80.0-c10-source/tools/build/src/build/toolset.jam:44: in toolset.using from module toolset
/media/y/e/carla-ue4-dev/Build/boost-1.80.0-c10-source/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:543: in process-explicit-toolset-requests from module build-system
/media/y/e/carla-ue4-dev/Build/boost-1.80.0-c10-source/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:610: in load from module build-system
/media/y/e/carla-ue4-dev/Build/boost-1.80.0-c10-source/tools/build/src/kernel/modules.jam:294: in import from module modules
/media/y/e/carla-ue4-dev/Build/boost-1.80.0-c10-source/tools/build/src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:135: in module scope from module
Util/BuildTools/Linux.mk:142: recipe for target 'setup' failed
make: *** [setup] Error 1
The above is what I have been getting regardless of what I have tried, I have clang-10, 8 and 11 installed and on the added to cxx and cc path as well installed g++-10, 8 and 11, but there is a fundamental problem: clang-11 is required to build b2, but carla requires clang-10 as a user specified requirement, which means the build checks for two different versions of the same software and would fail if one is not set. This is my basic understanding of this. Has anyone come across this problem or have a solution that would help?

I can recommend using the dev branch.
